# Python Creating raw audio

Tags: python, audio, audio-streaming

I use Windows 7.  All I want to do is create raw audio and stream it to a speaker.  After that, I want to create classes that can generate sine progressions (basically, a tone that slowly gets more and more shrill).  After that, I want to put my raw audio into audio codecs and containers like .WAV and .MP3 without going insane.  How might I be able to achieve this in Python **without using dependencies that don't come with a standard install**?

I looked up a great deal of files, descriptions, and related questions from here and all over the internet.  I read about PCM and ADPCM, as well as A/D Converters.  Where I get lost is somewhere between the ratio of byte input --> Kbps output, and all that stuff.

Really, all I want is for somebody to please be able to point me in the right direction to learn the audio formats precisely, and how to use them in Python (but first I want to start with raw audio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This questions really has 2 parts:

1. How do I generate audio signals
2. How do I play audio signals through the speakers.

I wrote a simple wrapper around the python std lib's `wave` module, called [pydub](http://pydub.com), which you can look at (on [github](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)) as a point of reference for how to manipulate raw audio data.

I generally just export the audio data to a file and then play it using VLC player. IMHO there's no reason to write a bunch of code to playback audio unless you're making a synthesizer or a game or some other realtime app.

Anyway, I hope that helps you get started :)

Comment: I am! (making an application for audio editing, just beginning).  Thanks for the link and the help!